# C# Selenium simulate keyup with ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I'm currently testing the behavior of a text input which apply filtering on a list on keyup event while typing the search term.

I have the following piece of code:

```
public IWebElement txtSearchInput => _chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@class, 'search-input')]"));

public void TypeSearchInput(string searchTerm)
{
    txtSearchInput.Click();
    txtSearchInput.SendKeys(searchTerm);
}
```

which successfully adds the search term in the input but does not fire up the filtering because the keyup event is not simulated (so the list is not filtered).

What I tried so far was to append the above method with `txtSearchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Up);` but did not work and I cannot see any workaround on this.

This is a reference for the front-end implementation written on Angular:

```
     <input type="text"
            class="search-input"
            placeholder="Type to filter.."
            [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" 
            (keyup)="filterUsers()"/>
```

Any ideas/help would be much appreciated. Just to highlight the setup is SpecFlow, Selenium, ChromeDriver, VS 2022. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Keys](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Keys.htm) class of Selenium framework and send the Enter key, so I can assume that filtering will work after Enter key send.

```
txtSearchInput.SendKeys(searchTerm + Keys.Enter);
```

---

UPDATE:

Because this is an angular site, Selenium should wait until angular initialization.

So here is the function for waiting until page loads fully:

```
private void WaitForAngular(IWebDriver driver)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    wait.Until(webDriver =>
    {
        return ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver)
            .ExecuteScript(
                "return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().findIndex(x=>!x.isStable()) === -1")
            .Equals(true);
    });
}
```

Thanks [this article](https://medium.com/code-divoire/angular-testability-dealing-with-selenium-or-protractor-timeouts-84016fcec889) for right direction.

And the calling code:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://angularsamplegithubproject.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/");
WaitForAngular(driver);
string xpath = "//input[contains(@class, 'search-input')]";
IWebElement txtSearchInput = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
txtSearchInput.Click();
txtSearchInput.SendKeys("moj");
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't work for me. I also tried adding ```txtSearchInput.Submit();``` but still. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Can you provide a testing url?

Comment: Sure, but be aware of the rate limit http://angularsamplegithubproject.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 1):

After applying several techniques, it seems that the issue was the ChromeDriver speed and not that the keyup is not fired.

As a workaround I ended up with the following amend:

```
        public void TypeSearchInput(string searchTerm)
        {
            txtSearchInput.Click();
            foreach (var character in searchTerm)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                txtSearchInput.SendKeys(character.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I hope this will be helpful for anyone struggling with the same issue.

Comment: This solution works because of Thread.Sleep(200) which is enough for angular initialization. Please look at my updated answer.

Comment: Indeed, this is why ny solution works (as I stated due to the webdriver speed). Thanks for taking the time to investigate. I just upvoted your answer as it worked for this case too